# how do i convert binary to a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-conversion

I was working in an algorithm where I needed binary of a file. I used the following code to print file's binary.

```
with open('img.jpg', 'rb') as file:
    print("".join(bin(b)[2:] for b in file.read()))
```

I got the binary of the file. Now I want to know how do I convert the output of the above code, the binary(101001001), back to a file.

Comment: Can you add more clarity to your question please?

Comment: If you can `read()` a file in `'rb'` mode (read/byte), surely you can `write()` a file with `'wb'` mode?

Comment: @disp_name I edited it

Comment: @Idlehands it says, TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'